# Can you rename columns in an R "formattable", without losing previously applied formatting?

Tags: r, formattable

grateful for any thoughts on a very minor issue I have.

I have created a table using the excellent formattable package in R, in which the column headers use the associated variable name. This is fine for internal work, but isn't how I intend to present them for their final use. To make them more human readable for the final table, I renamed them, but the new names are a little unwieldy, so I save this to the last step. However, any variables I rename lose the previously applied formatting.

The obvious solution is to rename before I carry out any formatting, but as mentioned, the names can be a little verbose for code. Is there a way to rename the columns as a last step, but not lose the previously applied formatting? I've yet to find a solution in the package documentation, but as I'm relatively new to R, it's very possible I have overlooked something very obvious - or that this approach is considered bad practice, so isn't something that would be advised.

I've included a working example below. I'm using R v3.5.2 and formattable version 0.2.0.1 - due to workplace security, I am limited by what packages (and their versions) I can use. Many thanks in advance for any thoughts.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)
data("iris")

# A very simple summary of iris data
my_table <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_sepal_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
    mean_sepal_width = mean(Sepal.Width)
  )

#Create my formattable with some arbitrary formatting
my_formattable <- formattable(
  my_table,
  align = c ("l", "r", "r"),
  list(
    Species = formatter("span", style = ~ style(
      color = "grey", font.weight = "bold"
    )),
    mean_sepal_length = color_bar('lightseagreen'),
    mean_sepal_width = color_bar('pink')
  )
)

my_formattable

# Change a column header to something more human-readable
my_formattable_renamed_cols <-
  my_formattable %>%  rename("Mean sepal length (cm)" = mean_sepal_length)

#Renamed columns lose their formatting
my_formattable_renamed_cols
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_table <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise(
        `Mean sepal length (cm)` = mean(Sepal.Length),
        `Mean sepal width (cm)` = mean(Sepal.Width)
      )
    
    #Create my formattable with some arbitrary formatting
    my_formattable <- formattable(
      my_table,
      align = c ("l", "r", "r"),
      list(Species = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey", font.weight = "bold")),
        `Mean sepal length (cm)` = color_bar('lightseagreen'), `Mean sepal width (cm)` = color_bar('pink'))
    )
```

[image: formatted_image]

Comment: Thanks for this - however, I wondered if there's a way to rename the column headers as a last step? So apply the column formatting using the original column names, and then "prettify" the column titles as a last step?